# Using NLog's aspnet-item:variable inside Task.Run?

Tags: .net-core, nlog

My Nlog.config contains this template :

```
 <target xsi:type="Console" name="Console"
            layout="${aspnet-item:variable:requestId} ${newline} ..." />
```

I'm using .net core (with a docker).

In an awaitable code , I do see the value of `item:variable:requestId` becuase I use :

```
 _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["requestId"] = "dummyvalue";
```

So the nlog can read it from context.

However , if my `loggerService` runs inside a `Task.Run` , then I don't see values. ( becuaes Task.run doesn't have `HttpContext`)

**Question:**

Is there a code API that I can manually set the `aspnet-item:variable:requestId` value ?
or is there another option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code:

```
MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("MyValueName", myValue);
```

In Nlog.config:

```
<target layout="${mdlc:item=MyValueName}" includeMdlc="true">
```

Comment: if i put this inside the task.run , will it affect other code which is not in the task.run ?

Comment: Depends. In general this value persists for entire call and is good e.g. for request correlation IDs. On the other hand we use this approach in a background job that generates a new ID for each Task and this works. So for your case probably not a full solution, but may be it will bring you further.

Comment: I want it to be for the entire call. so if main thread `A` create Task.Run `B` , then I want that B will contain A's info.I was asking about request C. will it see A's value ?

Comment: No, if you make two calls, e.g. to a REST endpoint, than each thread will have its own value.